# How should I organize my code if I want to define a class which consists of instances of another class?

Tags: python, class, oop, organization

I am having trouble deciding how I want to organize my code. I am building a simulation for an electric power system and want to define a class called "Plant" which contains "Transformer" and "Switch" objects. 
I don't know if it is a good idea to make these objects private to the class Plant. 
Also, I am unsure as to how I should organize these objects inside of a "Plant" object; should I just have a list of transformers which this plant contains or is there a better way to organize my data?

Basically, I am looking for advice on how I should organize my classes which are made up of other classes, or what I should consider when deciding this.

Oh, and I'm using python by the way.

Comment: Not only are private classes not a good idea, they're not even possible in Python.

Comment: Do you have a reference that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: A ```Plant``` instance should contain instances of ```Switches``` and ```Transformers``` so I imagine ```Plant``` would have one or more container/collection attributes and methods to add and access the individual items in the collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to think about the use cases for each of these objects in more detail. How do you expect to access each of these objects and what types of manipulations do you expect to make? This will give you a better idea of how to structure your code. As for making the attributes private, it probably doesnt matter this early on.

Answer (score -1):

Something along these lines should suit you

```
class Transformer():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        //initfunctions

    def other_function(self):

    //more fns

class Switch():
    def __init__(self):
        //initfunctions

    def other_function(self):

    //more fns

class Plant():
    def __init__(self):
        self.transformers = []
        self.switches = []

    def add_transformer(self, transformer):
        self.transformers.append(transformer)

    def create_transformer(self, name):
        self.transformers.append(Transformer(name))

    def print_transformers(self):
        for trans in self.transformers:
            print trans.name
```

and then you can use this in your main code like:

```
plant = Plant()
trans1 = Transformer('trans1')
plant.add_transformer(trans1)
plant.print_transformers()
```

This would then simply output

```
trans1
```

Comment: What does `plant.add_transformer()` do that `plant.transformers.append()` does not? Why did you add knowledge of `Transformer` to `class Plant` when it doesn't benefit anything? Is `plant.print_transformers()` better than `print(plant.transformers)` in any way? Why did you add so much junk code?

Comment: @msw Isn't this a matter of what the contract is, given the OP didn't provide more details hard to tell if this does or does not benefit anything. Maybe the OP comes from a more classic OOP language, because this is effectively what the OP asked for.